# How can I get a reference to a KnockoutJS component template that has been loaded using RequireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I want to get a reference a KnockoutJS component template with the component being loaded by RequireJS.

Here is the registration:

```
ko.components.register("main-content", { require: "components/main-content/main-content" });
```

Here is the component ViewModel:

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "text!./main-content.html"], function($, ko, template) {

    function MainContentViewModel() {
    }

    return { viewModel: MainContentViewModel, template: template };
});
```

And here is the component template:

```
<div class="main-content-container">
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is in one of my JS scripts, I want to be able to get the template of the component mentioned above and store it in a variable. Like:

```
var t = require("text!../components/main-content.html");
```

but this seems to not work. How can I get a reference to the component or template. I also tried adding my script inside a require and in the list of dependencies, I added the component thinking I might be able to use it, but its throwing an error.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

My directory structure is like this (some things omitted):

```
+ js
  - main.js
+ components
  + main-content
    - main-content.html
    - main-content.js
```

The code that is trying to get a reference is in main.js. Right now, this is the code I am using to try to get a reference:

```
var t = require([], "text!../components/main-content/main-content.html");
```

There is no error, but the value of variable t when I check in console is:

```
function g(c, d, p)
```

which I don't know what it means or what to do with it.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that any string value I put in the require call results in *function g(c, d, p)*. Even if I put an empty string like this:

```
var t = require([], "");
```

which probably means what I am doing is wrong or lacking.

Comment: What do you mean on "seems to not work"? Do you get some error? Why do you need the template in a different script? Phisically where is the main-conten.html stored on your server? Based on your current code sample this should work: `var t = require("text!components/main-content/main-content.html");`

Comment: @nemesv: Thanks for commenting. Added some additional info.

Comment: The simplest solution is to extend your `main.js` module to also take dependency on your text file. If this is a conditionally needed dependency then you need to write: `require(["text!components/main-content/main-content.html"], function (template) { // you have the HTML in template });` because require.js will load the modules async